# SSDT 2013 new database Project missing

Tags: sql-server, templates, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

This might be a trivial error in my setup but I cannot seem to find where I went wrong in stalling SSDT 2013  with SQl Server and having the open to create a new database template

please see image

what I expect to be in the list in a sql template with the option to create a new database project 
could someone tell me what i'm missing ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For database projects you'll need to install a version of Visual Studio that supports it - in your case it looks like you ran the standalone SSDT-BI installer which installs SSIS, SSAS and SSRS templates. This doesn't include database project templates. What you need is to install one of the VS versions with support - there are 2 Express versions (Express for Web and Express for Windows Desktop) and 3 paid versions (Premium, Pro, Ultimate). Here is a quote from the [SSDT blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx) explaining this:

> Visual Studio 2013 - VS 2013 now has SQL Server tooling built in and shipped as part of the core product.  Database Projects, SQL tools (such as schema compare & data compare), and the online experiences through SSOX are all included with the RTM version.  **We have full project and SSOX support in VS Express for Web and Express for Windows Desktop, so we have discontinued our stand-alone integrated shell offering.**  We have a component update feed that will use VS Update to push notification to users.  To manually check for updates, go to the Tools > Extensions and Updates... menu to open the dialog.  We will continue to post announcements on our blog and forum that a release is available and what is included in that update.

Comment: Does the BI standalone allow for a sql Database template to be addedd?

Comment: The VS2013 Express versions are free to use for development and include full Database tooling support (Database project templates, connected development, Azure SQL Database integration, and full Database Unit Test support coming in the next vesion). This is what you should use if you don't have a paid subscription. I believe that if you install this it should add database template support to the standalone Visual Studio shell that SSDT-BI installs, which would mean you could develop all your SQL Server projects in one place. Let me know if that's not the case though.

Comment: Hi Kevin 
I install VS Express for desktop this then did a ssdt update and now I have the database configuration within the application (SSDT) to use, which is what I wanted 
I'm not sure of there being any limitations yet. So a mix of SSDT BI and VS Exrpess did the job (confusing slightly that it wasnt already in SSDT) 
Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm just finding this false in my case. I have Visual Studios 2013 premium edition which did not include the database projects or sql tools at all.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio 2013 are you using? You need to have either the Ultimate, Premium or Pro version for SSDT ([Link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx)).
[image: Visual Studio Versions]

If you do have the right version of Visual Studio then you may need to re-run the installer and opt in to SQL Server Data Tools during setup.

Comment: Hi guys all great comments that I am looking at right now 
My set up does'nt contain a paid for version of VS because this is for development only. What I tried to achieve he was a working BI environment incl the database project templates which i have working with GIT lab as version control 
everything seem to be working aprt from the database templates (as shown above) hopefully this make sense and I'm happy for comments if Ive gone about this completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it several years ago. I needed to reinstall SSMS with Data Tools. Unfortunately I am encountering the same issue now, but luckily I had documented the issue at the time. I am finding that because there are newer versions of both VS and SSMS, it is hard to find the proper downloads.
From my documentation (3 years ago) None of the attempts to correct the Visual Studio install directly (SSDTBI_x86_ENU download from Microsoft) were successful, but once we did a complete reinstall of SQL Server 2014 which included the Data Tools, the needed template was available in the Add New Project dialog, and the previously incompatible projects found in GitHub******Report.sln were now compatible.